# Python function to connect to MS SQL using connection parameters from environment variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration, odbc

I have the following file that is included in others. I realise I need to put in `try/except` but for the purposes of this question, the below should suffice

We're using MS SQL

**Function**

Already done in the example below. Except for `try/except` am I missing anything obvious?

**Class**

I was looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209627/python-writing-my-class-with-with-statement and was wondering at what point does using classes make sense with regards to the below? What would using classes with regards to the below look like?

**Method**

Should I consider moving all of those global constants into a method that accepts no parameters and produces a connection string instead? If so, what would that look like?

```
"""
Useful SQL connections
"""
import os
import pyodbc

DB_SERVER = os.environ.get('DB_SERVER')
DB_NAME = os.environ.get('DB_NAME')
DB_USER = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
DB_PASS = os.environ.get('DB_PASS')
DB_DRIVER = os.environ.get('DB_DRIVER')

def db_connect():
    return pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={DB_DRIVER};SERVER={DB_SERVER};DATABASE={DB_NAME};UID={DB_USER};PWD={DB_PASS}')

def get_inpatients():
    """
    Getting all the inpatients currently sitting in A&E
    """
    with db_connect() as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()

    for row in cursor.execute('EXEC spGetInpatients'):
        yield row[0]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that this question has enough context. The place most sorely wanting for a class here is currently an `Inpatient`, but you haven't given us enough information on the query to be able to show what that class would look like.

Comment: Have updated - it is MSSQL

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite enough: ideally, show the columns returned by your stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, a class should be created when a certain amount of functions in the execution of a program share the same data or need the same data to operate. When creating classes there's a process of specialization and abstraction where you might make a large class that gets divided after refactoring into a superclass and two or many more others that inherit from the superclass.

In your case I would consider creating a class for the database as an interface that would handle the connection parameters.

If the program keeps on expanding and you need to add more operations apart from *get_inpatients*, I would consider creating classes for the models or objects of the domain problem that would take a database connection class and execute queries using it.

**Edit:**

This solution may seem a little too verbose but I think this would help you isolate the connection to the data source and the methods of fetching the data from the data handling. In other terms, the DatabaseConnection class would hide from whoever fetching data the implementation details (connection handling, etc...) and the DatabaseInterface would hide from whoever requesting data the implementation details of the data source.

```
class DatabaseConnection:
    def __init__(self, config_params: dict) -> None:
        # check the parameters and raise Exceptions
        self.config = config_params
        self._set_up_connection()

    def _set_up_connection(self) -> None:
        # here you would set up the connection

    def execute_query(self, query) -> None:
        # you could use this method from 
        # outside this class to execute 
        # queries and handle them

class DatabaseInterface:
    def __init__(self, db_connection: DatabaseConnection) -> None:
        # this would be the interface 
        # that would use the connection
        self.db_conn = db_connection

    def get_inpatients(self) -> list:
        # methods like these would be
        # used to fetch the data
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond - are there any examples that would help me go on my way? What would the advantages be? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202818/classes-vs-functions is quite damning with regards to using classes for this kind of behaviour so it was more of "why with examples"

Answer (score 1):

### Passing arguments

Consider using parsed command line arguments, instead of environment variables. If you want to support the latter, you can still default to them.

You can also use the command line arguments to decide which db-operation you want to perform.

### Redundant code

`db_connect()` is redundant and has side-effects.
You can generate the connection string on a superordinate level and use `pyodbc.connect` directly.

### Suggested change

```py
"""Useful SQL connections."""

from argparse import ArgumentParser, Namespace
from getpass import getpass
from os import environ
from typing import Any, Iterator

from pyodbc import connect


def parse_args(description: str = __doc__) -> Namespace:
    """Return parsed command line arguments."""

    parser = ArgumentParser(description=description)
    parser.add_argument('server', help='database server')
    parser.add_argument('database', help='database name')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-d', '--driver', metavar='driver', default=environ.get('DB_DRIVER'),
        help='database driver'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-u', '--user', metavar='name', default=environ.get('DB_USER'),
        help='database user'
    )
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action', required=True)
    subparsers.add_parser(name='get_inpatients')
    return parser.parse_args()


def get_passwd() -> str:
    """Returns the password from the environment variables or reads it."""

    if passwd := environ.get('DB_PASS'):
        return passwd

    return getpass('Password: ')


def get_inpatients(connect_str: str) -> Iterator[Any]:
    """
    Getting all the inpatients currently sitting in A&E
    """
    with connect(connect_str) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()

    for row in cursor.execute('EXEC spGetInpatients'):
        yield row[0]


def main() -> None:
    """Runs the script."""

    args = parse_args()
    connect_str = (
        f'DRIVER={args.driver};'
        f'SERVER={args.server};'
        f'DATABASE={args.database};'
        f'UID={args.user};'
        f'PWD={get_passwd()}'
    )
    
    if args.action == 'get_inpatients':
        print(*get_inpatients(connect_str))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Non-interactive version for Joe User

If you want the script to be non-interactive for the average user, you can of course pre-define the configuration parameters in the environment variables. You might want to access mandatory arguments by index, so that you get an early exception thrown, if those are not set.

```py
"""Useful SQL connections."""

from argparse import ArgumentParser, Namespace
from logging import getLogger
from os import environ
from typing import Any, Iterator

from pyodbc import connect


LOGGER = getLogger(__file__)


def parse_args(description: str = __doc__) -> Namespace:
    """Return parsed command line arguments."""

    parser = ArgumentParser(description=description)
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action', required=True)
    subparsers.add_parser(name='get_inpatients')
    return parser.parse_args()


def get_inpatients(connect_str: str) -> Iterator[Any]:
    """
    Getting all the inpatients currently sitting in A&E
    """
    with connect(connect_str) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()

    for row in cursor.execute('EXEC spGetInpatients'):
        yield row[0]


def main() -> None:
    """Runs the script."""

    args = parse_args()

    try:
        connect_str = (
            f"DRIVER={environ['DB_DRIVER']};"
            f"SERVER={environ['DB_SERVER']};"
            f"DATABASE={environ['DB_NAME']};"
            f"UID={environ['DB_USER']};"
            f"PWD={environ['DB_PASS']}"
        )
    except KeyError:
        LOGGER.error('Missing configuration parameters.')
        LOGGER.error('Please contact your sysadmin.')
        return
    
    
    if args.action == 'get_inpatients':
        print(*get_inpatients(connect_str))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Library version

For a library it may be useful to have missing enironment args handled with a custom exception, since `KeyError`s might also occur elsewhere.

```py
...

class MissingConnectionParams(Exception):
    """Indicates missing connection parameters."""


def get_connect_str() -> str:
    """Returns the connection string."""

    try:
        return (
            f"DRIVER={environ['DB_DRIVER']};"
            f"SERVER={environ['DB_SERVER']};"
            f"DATABASE={environ['DB_NAME']};"
            f"UID={environ['DB_USER']};"
            f"PWD={environ['DB_PASS']}"
        )
    except KeyError as key_error:
        raise MissingConnectionParams() from key_error
```

Comment: Thank you - we would not be asking the user for any details as these would inevitably be non technical staff - the idea is to have this as a library other scripts call (I should have made this clear - apologies)

Comment: I disagree with the introduction of `argparse` in this case. It's both typical and secure for environmental variables to be used for connection string parameters, to the point where some RDBMS tools actually look there for their defaults.

Comment: @RichardNeumann I also have same question as Reinderien - that using Env Vars to pass in connection information is what seems to be the recommended approach from a security point of view, especially in sandboxed type docker deployments.  I've used both approaches and typically use the Env Var approach now, especially as using tools like Kubernetes makes that quite easy to manage.